# How to convert a camel-case string to dashes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, camelcasing

I want to convert these strings:

```
fooBar
FooBar
```

into:

```
foo-bar
-foo-bar
```

How would I do this in JavaScript the most elegant and performant way for any given string?

Comment: Split into an array of characters, check for uppercase characters, replace them by their lowercase pendent + the dash in front, combine the array back to a string.

Comment: @Danmoreng Wouldn't a regex be better?

Comment: Sure you could also use a regex with [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: i guess the most elegant- would most likely not the most performant-solution

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use `replace` with a regex like:

```
let dashed = camel.replace(/[A-Z]/g, m => "-" + m.toLowerCase());
```

which matches all uppercased letters and replace them with their lowercased versions preceded by `"-"`.

**Example:**

```js
console.log("fooBar".replace(/[A-Z]/g, m => "-" + m.toLowerCase()));
console.log("FooBar".replace(/[A-Z]/g, m => "-" + m.toLowerCase()));
```

Answer (score 16):

For those who do not need the preceding hyphen:

```js
console.log ("CamelCase".replace(/[A-Z]/g, (match, offset) => (offset > 0 ? '-' : '') + match.toLowerCase()))
```

Answer (score 12):

Maybe you could use `kebabCase` from lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#kebabCase

Comment: If @timo-ernst trying to use dataset, the problem is `FooBar` converted to `-foo-bar` instead of `foo-bar`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `replace()` with regex. Then use `toLowerCase()`

```js
let camel = (s) => s.replace(/[A-Z]/g, '-$&').toLowerCase()

console.log(camel('fooBar'))
console.log(camel('FooBar'))
```

`

Comment: One note: you don't need to group the match. Just remove the parens and use `$&`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It's nice but there is warning notice in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastMatch)

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#dasherizestring--string from **underscore.string** library.

Comment: I like the "Don't reinvent the wheel approach"

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

Simple case:

```
"fooBar".replace( /([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2' ).toLowerCase();   
"FooBar".replace( /([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2' ).toLowerCase();
```

Edge case: this can get an extreme case where you have a single char.

```
"FooBarAFooBar".replace(/([A-Z])/g, (g) => `-${g[0].toLowerCase()}`)
```

Comment: OP wants to include the first letter too.

Comment: hi @ibrahimmahrir thanks to let me notice that, 
this should fix his problem and also consider the edge case where he has a single char in capital letter.
"FooBarAFooBar".replace(/([A-Z])/g, (g) => `-${g[0].toLowerCase()}`)

Comment: Unnecessarily complicated regex pattern, that's why you need to separately handle single uppercase

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
const makeItDashed = camelCased => {
   let dashed = ``
   camelCased.split(``).map(ch => {{dashed += ch.toUpperCase() == ch ? `-${ch.toLowerCase()}` : ch}})
   return dashed
}

console.log(makeItDashed(`fooBar`))
console.log(makeItDashed(`FooBar`))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple way to do that, you can use [CaseParser](https://github.com/NandoMB/caseparser) to do that.

All you need to do is install the package to your project:

```bash
npm add caseparser
```

And then, use it like the following example. If you pass a string 'fooBar', you could convert it into many 'cases':

```
// import using ESM
import caseparser from 'caseparser';
// or using CommonJS
const caseparser = require('caseparser');

// Using CaseParser library
caseparser.camelToDash('fooBar');       // 'foo-bar'
caseparser.camelToPascal('fooBar');     // 'FooBar'
caseparser.camelToSnake('fooBar');      // 'foo_bar'
caseparser.camelToUpperDash('fooBar');  // 'FOO-BAR'
caseparser.camelToUpperSnake('fooBar'); // 'FOO_BAR'
```

It converts json object's keys and arrays too. For the latest versions (2.x.x) now supports typesafe after the conversion!

I hope to help you :)